# What does this wecho command do?

Tags: files, find, echo, process-substitution, tree

I found a script that makes a file list. The list looks like this

```
/home/usr/example_directory
/home/usr/example_directory/file1.txt
/home/usr/example_directory/file2.txt
/home/usr/different_directory
/home/usr/different_directory/file3.txt
/home/usr/different_directory/file4.txt
```

The script is

```
wecho "
cat 
   <(find /home/usr/example_directory) 
   <(find /home/usr/different_directory) 
   | bgzip > filelist.txt.gz
"
```

Within the quotes I think I understand what is happening. Using process substitution to pipe multiple commands to a file and compressing it to filelist, however I don't know what `wecho` is doing - it doesn't even appear to be a function. Also, why does the pipe needs to be within double quotes?

I've run this in bash and it says wecho command not found, and if you run this with echo instead then it just prints the script to stdout.

Comment: Check the script for a function called `wecho`

Comment: Sounds like a simple typo in the script.

Comment: If the script produces that output, then "wecho" exists. Just add `whatis wecho` before it is executed, and it will tell you.